# Passing Generics into method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class:

```
public class ClassA<T>
{
  public T Value {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

ClassA can have a value of any type, however: I need to be able to set other properties of anything that is ClassA regardless of the type value. So I have a method:

```
public void DoWork(ClassA<object> source, ClassA<object> destination)
{
  destination.Description = source.Description;
}
```

However when I try to do this I get a runtime error saying that:
cannot convert from `ClassA<DateTime>` to `ClassA<object>`

I thought that anything could be passed as an object... I've looked all over the web for something similar, maybe I'm just not getting the keywords right.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `Description` will be a string on both sides of the assign. Where is the code that makes this run?

Comment: What you have there builds/runs. whats the problem?

Comment: I put your code into LinqPad and it ran for me.  I guess we need to see how you're calling your code.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are testing that uses the DoWork function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do that.

If you could pass a `ClassA<int>` into a method accepting a `ClassA<object> wrapper` then that method would be able to call `wrapper.Value = "not an integer";`.  What should happen then?  You've just set a string to an object that can only hold integers.  Since the compiler knows it can't enforce what you could put it, it just doesn't let you pass the object in the first place.

As for the actual solution, two come to mind.

You could make your method generic, if that's an option:

```
public void DoWork<TSource, TDestination>(ClassA<TSource> source, ClassA<TDestination> destination)
{
  destination.Description = source.Description;
}
```

Or you could make a covariant interface:

```
public interface IWrapper<out T>
{
    T Value {get;}
    string Description {get;set;}
}

public class ClassA<T> : IWrapper<T>
{
    //...
}

public void DoWork(IWrapper<object> source, IWrapper<object> destination)
{
  destination.Description = source.Description;
}
```

For your `DoWork` method you don't even actually use the `Value`, so you could make the interface non-generic, non-covariant, and just remove `Value`.  The advantage here is that you could use that interface to access the value properties of any number of `ClassA` objects that have a common base type.

Comment: You could also have a signature that allowed various generic types on each parameter, there is no need to constrain it to a single type (see my answer).

Comment: @James Yep, I upvoted your answer as that was a great suggestion.  Since this answer has been accepted I put that in mine as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to be able to use various generic types you can specify a different type for each parameter e.g.

```
public void Work<TSource, TDestination>(ClassA<TSource> source, ClassA<TDestination> destination)
{
    destination.Description = source.Description;
}
```

However, it looks like your real issue here is you have common properties on a *generic* class, you can eliminate the generic part by using a common interface e.g.

```
public interface IClassA
{
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA<T> : IClassA
{
    ...
}

public void DoWork(IClassA source, IClassA destination)
{
    destination.Description = source.Description;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with extension methods. It has to do with generic variance. It's simplest to see it like this:

```
ClassA<DateTime> x = new ClassA<DateTime>();
ClassA<Object> y = x;
```

This will fail to compile in the same way.

As of C# 4, there is some *limited* support for generic variance, but:

- Only for interfaces and delegates
- Only for reference types
- Only where explicitly declared

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) for more details, or [Eric Lippert's blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/).

That explains why it doesn't work. As for how to fix it - making the extension method generic as per Jason's answer is probably the simplest approach.

Note that at the moment, you haven't even got an extension method - you'd need to declare it in a top-level non-generic static class, like this:

```
public static void DoWork<T>(this ClassA<T> source, ClassA<T> destination)
{
    destination.Description = source.Description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean this:

```
public void DoWork<T>(ClassA<T> source, ClassA<T> destination)
{
  destination.Description = source.Description;
}
```